# A suitable 'do nothing' lambda expression in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I sometimes find myself wanting to make placeholder 'do nothing' lambda expressions, similar to saying:

```
def do_nothing(*args):
    pass
```

But the following syntax is illegal since lambda expressions attempt to return whatever is after the colon, and you can't return `pass`.

```
do_nothing = lambda *args: pass
```

So I was wondering, would the following expression be a suitable replacement for the above?

```
do_nothing = lambda *args: None
```

Since the `do_nothing` function above technically returns `None`, is it okay to make a lambda expression that returns `None` to use as a placeholder lambda expression? Or is it bad practice?

Comment: It does do the same thing as the `do_nothing` function, but it's not clear why you need to use a `lambda` for it.

Comment: I wanted to use `lambda` purely for readability of code, since I'm personally not a fan of nested functions and the application I wanted to use the expression in would be a third nested function. I'm also simply just interested in other opinions about using this coding trope.

Comment: In idiomatic Python, most places where you would need a do-nothing function accept `None`, even though it isn't callable. To wit: `filter(None, alist)`

Comment: Since all do-nothing functions do the same nothing, you could just define `do_nothing` in one place and then pass `do_nothing` whenever you want to pass a do-nothing.  There's no need to redefine it with a new lambda (or full function def) every time you want to use it.

Comment: `mock.Mock()` can be your dummy callable, accepting any parameters. But it returns another Mock and it may result in weird bugs. Changing it to `mock.Mock(return_value=None)` can be still buggy since you can try to get an attribute from it and it will work, returning another Mock.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This:

```
def do_nothing(*args):
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
lambda *args: None
```

With some minor differences in that one is a `lambda` and one isn't. (For example, `__name__` will be `do_nothing` on the function, and `<lambda>` on the lambda.) Don't forget about `**kwargs`, if it matters to you. Functions in Python without an explicit `return <x>` return `None`. This is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> A call always returns some value, possibly None, unless it raises an exception.

I've used similar functions as default values, say for example:

```
def long_running_code(progress_function=lambda percent_complete: None):
    # Report progress via progress_function.
```

Comment: This also works in ternary conditional expressions: DEBUG = print if DEBUGSW == True else lambda *args: None

Answer (score 69):

If you truly want a full do nothing lambda function, make sure to gobble up `*args` *and* `*kwargs`.

```
noop = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
```

In all its glorious action

```
>>> noop = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
>>> noop("yes", duck_size="horse", num_ducks=100)
>>>
```

---

### Side Note

Since the accepted answer is only using `*args`, I *must* point out that you will do yourself a favor for the future by including the `**kwargs` handling. If you ever try to use the `noop` somewhere deep away in your code and you forgot that it *doesn't* take `kwargs`, it will be quite the Exception to doing nothing:

```
In [2]: do_nothing('asdf', duck="yes")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-efbd722f297c> in <module>()
----> 1 do_nothing('asdf', duck="yes")

TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'duck'
```

Comment: If you assign the function to a variable, it is much better to do it the normal way: `def noop(*args, **kwargs): return None`

Answer (score 29):

Sometimes lambda functions are used for data transformation, and in that case 'do nothing' means to return the input, i.e.

`lambda x: x`

To return none you can write

`lambda x: None`

Comment: That's not the same as a do-nothing function that returns None.

Comment: I like this thought. It's more like the multiplicative `identity` than `do_nothing`. Maybe there's a case for having one of each.

Answer (score 21):

This is the simplest lambda expression:

```
do_nothing = lambda: None
```

No arguments required and the minimal required return.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution

Comment: This raises `TypeError` when arguments, positional or keyword, are passed.

Answer (score 6):

In **Python 3** you don't even need to define any functions for that. Calling `type(None)` will return you the `NoneType` constructor, which you can use for doing nothing: `type(None)()`. Keep in mind that the `NoneType` constructor only takes 0 arguments.

In **Python 2**, though, creating instances of `NoneType` is impossible, so `lambda: None` would make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

Besides this expression

```
lambda *args: None
```

there is another graceful expression using [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis):

```
lambda *args: ...
```

This can also be useful in case the function has no arguments (callback for example):

```
lambda: None

lambda: ...
```