# How to declare a function "to do nothing" in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm learning `Python` and `Django` and I have a question.

I would like to know how to define a function that does nothing and continue with the flow of program execution while I read an archive.

```
while True:
     empty()
     with open(r'archive.txt') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            print(line)
```

How I can write a function that does nothing like for example:

```
def empty():
```

Comment: `def empty(): pass`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A suitable 'do nothing' lambda expression in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738412/a-suitable-do-nothing-lambda-expression-in-python)

Comment: i dont want pass parameters to the function just for the flow of the program continues without a break.

Comment: What's the point of this? Why call the function at all if you don't want it to do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is like in pure python

```
def empty():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 2.x:

```
def empty():
    pass
```

With Python 3.x you can also do this:

```
def empty():
    ... # this is called Ellipsis, simply three dots in a row
```